# SQL stored procedure, Column calculated from two other calculated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i want to insert `column3` values from `column1+column2(they are calculated columns).`

```
Column3 = Column1*.666+Column2*.3333
```

`Column1` and `Column2` are generated from case statements and they are fine but its just `Column3` which is based on 
`Column1` and `Column2`. Can anyone help me how can I calculate `Column3`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
         INSERT INTO IF_FUNDDETAILS  ( D.FUNDCODE,   D.FUNDNAME,  Column1,Column2, Column3)
            SELECT DISTINCT  D.FUNDCODE, D.FUNDNAME, 
    CASE WHEN  AVG( FD.INDUSTRYCONTRIBUTIONS)>80 THEN '80' ELSE '90' END AS Column1,
    CASE WHEN  AVG( FD.BENEFITSCONTRIBUTIONS)>50 THEN '50' ELSE '90' END AS Column2,
            FROM   DBO.WS_FUNDDETAIL AS D 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.V_FUNDNOOUTOFPOCKET AS NOP ON D.FUNDDETAILID = NOP.FUNDDETAILID 
            INNER JOIN DBO.WS_FUNDDATA AS FD ON NOP.FUNDREPORTID = FD.FUNDREPORTID 
            GROUP BY  D.FUNDCODE, D.FUNDNAME
```

Comment: Try too add those 2 cases

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Someone removed the MySQL tag, but perhaps this is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse the aliases in the same level of the query.  So, just repeat the `CASE` expressions:

```
INSERT INTO IF_FUNDDETAILS (D.FUNDCODE, D.FUNDNAME, Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT DISTINCT
    D.FUNDCODE,
    D.FUNDNAME, 
    CASE WHEN AVG(FD.INDUSTRYCONTRIBUTIONS) > 80 THEN 80 ELSE 90 END AS Column1,
    CASE WHEN AVG(FD.BENEFITSCONTRIBUTIONS) > 50 THEN 50 ELSE 90 END AS Column2,
    0.666 * (CASE WHEN AVG(FD.INDUSTRYCONTRIBUTIONS) > 80 THEN 80 ELSE 90 END) +
    0.333 * (CASE WHEN AVG(FD.BENEFITSCONTRIBUTIONS) > 50 THEN 50 ELSE 90 END) AS Column3
FROM DBO.WS_FUNDDETAIL AS D 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.V_FUNDNOOUTOFPOCKET AS NOP
    ON D.FUNDDETAILID = NOP.FUNDDETAILID 
INNER JOIN DBO.WS_FUNDDATA AS FD
    ON NOP.FUNDREPORTID = FD.FUNDREPORTID 
GROUP BY D.FUNDCODE,
         D.FUNDNAME
```

Note: I removed the single quotes around the number amounts in the `CASE` expressions since it appears you want to treat the results of those expressions as numbers, not text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it just with one insert statement.

What you can do is.

1. Insert into table with all values except column 3.
2. Update above row for column3 as

   update table tblName set Column3 = Column1*.666+Column2*.3333 where clause

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CTE.

```
;with cte
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT  D.FUNDCODE, D.FUNDNAME, 
    CASE WHEN  AVG( FD.INDUSTRYCONTRIBUTIONS)>80 THEN '80' ELSE '90' END AS Column1,
    CASE WHEN  AVG( FD.BENEFITSCONTRIBUTIONS)>50 THEN '50' ELSE '90' END AS Column2,
            FROM   DBO.WS_FUNDDETAIL AS D 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.V_FUNDNOOUTOFPOCKET AS NOP ON D.FUNDDETAILID = NOP.FUNDDETAILID 
            INNER JOIN DBO.WS_FUNDDATA AS FD ON NOP.FUNDREPORTID = FD.FUNDREPORTID 
            GROUP BY  D.FUNDCODE, D.FUNDNAME

)

INSERT INTO IF_FUNDDETAILS  ( FUNDCODE,   FUNDNAME,  Column1,Column2, Column3)
SELECT * , Column1*.666+Column2*.3333 AS Column3 from cte
```